# How do I count records based on time (month, year) ?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table (myItems) with an item "`id`" and "`date`". Now i want to read out, how many items there are per month (i also want to distinguish between October 2013 and October 2014).

I started with:

```
SELECT Count(okt.id) AS Oktober, Count(nov.id) AS November
FROM    `myItems` as okt,
        `myItems` as nov    
WHERE (okt.date between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-31') 
   OR (nov.date between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-30')
```

But it prints out a ridiculously large number. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing group by

Comment: You are doing a cross join on the table itself so the results are multiplied. You should group by year and month.

Comment: sounds good.. how would that look in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This will divide data into months and then do the COUNT :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oktober
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS November
FROM    `myItems`
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43cb2/2)

---

With YEAR integrated:

```
SELECT 2013 as Year
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oktober
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS November
FROM    `myItems`
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2013
UNION ALL
SELECT 2014 as Year
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oktober
     , SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS November
FROM    `myItems`
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2014;
;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43cb2/5)

---

With inspiration from @user77318

```
SELECT YEAR(date) as Year, month(date) as month, count(id) as count 
FROM myItems 
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date);
```

I personally recommend this, more beautiful. Then you can do all the presentation stuffs on Application Layer.

Comment: It says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Oktober , Count(CASE MONTH(`Start`) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0) ". maybe this doesnt work for mySQL?

Comment: I forgot the END keyword. Could you try again?

Comment: Works better, but it prints out 3 times the same number, which is not right... any idea?

Comment: No.. i guess it just counts ALL items now, not just those of november

Comment: Now its looking good! Do you also know, how i can merge the year into this query?

Comment: Please update your desired result into the question. How should it look like?

Comment: Well, if i did the query with the date format like this: '2013-10-01',
i can also distinguish between October 2014 and October 2013. I would like to do that, so i am asking, how to do that in the query you showed me (and which works perfectly fine except for that ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Group the result by month:

> SELECT month(date) as month, count(id) as count FROM myItems WHERE date between '2013-10-01' and '2013-11-30' GROUP BY MONTH(date);

Example of output result:

> Month | Count
>
> 10    | 100
>
> 11    | 200

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not using join, you are just giving the conditions. First try to join these 2 tables with the primary keys or with some unique and common data column. Then try to execute above query. Somthiong like this:-

```
SELECT Count(okt.id) AS Oktober, Count(nov.id) AS November
FROM    `myItems` as okt,
        `myItems` as nov    
WHERE okt.id = nov.id
AND (okt.date between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-31')
OR (nov.date between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-30');
```

May be this is helpful for you.

Comment: Im not sure i understood this the right way, but i have only one table "myItems", which i wnat to "devide" into the months the items are from.